# Using mutate() and mean() to get the average of columns whose names are stored in a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a simple function that I can re-use whenever I'm creating a composite score of several items.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
item_names = c("item1", "item2")

dat = dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(composite_score = mean( *what goes here?* ))
```

How do I get the mean of these values through specifying the column names, as I did in *item_names*?

I tried setting it up as below using the %in% operator, but it does not work.

```
item_names = c("item1", "item2")

dat = dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(composite_score = mean(df[, names(df) %in% item_names]))
```

Comment: You can use `composite_score = colMeans(df[, names(df) %in% item_names])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you use the function `c_across`. Specifically, you can do `mean(c_across(all_of(item_names)))`. This produces a column in which the composite score is the mean of `item1` and `item2` in that row, which seems to be what you are trying to do.

Let's use `mtcars` as an example:

```r
library(dplyr)

item_names = c("hp", "mpg")

mtcars %>%
  select(1:4) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(composite_score = mean(c_across(all_of(item_names))))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp composite_score
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110            65.5
#>  2  21       6  160    110            65.5
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93            57.9
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110            65.7
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175            96.8
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105            61.6
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245           130. 
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62            43.2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95            58.9
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123            71.1
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response.  You made my day!